# Sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction

In sentences given below, which pair of sentences (the "a" pair or the "b" pair) has the correct structure?

> **1a.** It is required **you to remind** in evening time.
>   **2a.** Mother’s Day is around the corner and we want **it to make** a special one!

Or

> **1b.** It is required **to remind you** in evening time.
>   **2b.** Mother’s Day is around the corner and we want **to make it** a special one!

Please give the justification, if possible.

Comment: what do you think about these sentence?

Comment: Not only are both sentences ungrammatical, they're *so* ungrammatical that I can't understand what they're supposed to be communicating. Can you explain what meaning you're trying to convey?

Comment: If I have asked you to get a XYZ book for me tomorrow and now, I asking about reminder then which one of above sentence’s structure is correct?

Comment: Same doubt (Order of words) in sentences given 1) Mother’s Day is around the corner and we want to make it a special one! 2) Mother’s Day is around the corner and we want it to make a special one!

Comment: From the examples it is not possible to understand who is reminding whom. Additional context is needed. If you want to change the example phrases, you need to edit your question.

Comment: Thank you Stoney for editing... @User3169, Now, is it possible for you to explain on question given above?

Comment: I'd fix them like this: A. *It is required **of** you to remind **us** in **the** evening time. Mother’s Day is around the corner and we want it to **be** a special one!* B. *It is required to remind you in **the** evening time. Mother’s Day is around the corner and we want to make it a special one!*

Comment: Thank you Damkerng...So Both sentences's (A and B) meaning are same...right

Answer (score 1):

Direct object pronouns always go after the verb.

Typical English word order is Subject-Verb-Object.  If you put object pronouns in front of the subject, it will strongly seem that you are trying to express the subject with them.

---

Some verbs take objects.  An object for verb X answers the question "who or what is being X'ed"

> I will remind you about this later.

"You" is an object here, it answers the question "who or what is being reminded."  Many verbs describe actions that happen to someone or something, i.e. they have a "target." but still wrong.
 but still wrong.

The order of words in English is very important.  In sentences that are not questions or commands the subject is usually expected to come before the verb.  So when you say something like:

> I will you remind about this later.

it sounds like you are trying to make the *subject* of "remind" both *I* and *you*.  So, reading this, I don't know who you are trying to say is doing the reminding.  It doesn't make sense.

*You* is both the second-person subject and object pronoun, so something like this:

> I will him remind about this later.

is easier to untangle.  Since *him* is an object pronoun, I can figure it out, but it still sounds very wrong.

---

For reference, here's a comparison between English subject and object pronouns.

```
Person               Subject Pronoun     Object Pronoun
-------------------- ------------------- -------------------
1st singular         I                   me
1st plural           we                  us

2nd singular         you                 you
2nd plural           you                 you

3rd singular m.      he                  him
3rd singular f.      she                 her
3rd plural           they                them
```

Comment: Could you pleaes elaborate? or pls provide an example, if possible

Comment: Thank you for explaining....But I have seen sentences like this (I want you to check about examination's date) where "you" comes before verb "to check", so is this incorrect?

Comment: No, it's correct.  I think with this, there are two phrases - *I want you* and *to check about the examination's date*.   *You* is the object of *I want*, and the phrase *to check about the examination's date*  qualifies *I want you*.